# Turned a second into unessential

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Do you want to say something?
Hang on, let me write it for you.
Remember that in every word you're saying,
I'm playing a part, it's true.

Want to imagine like, anythin'?
I'll prove it wrong, fool you!
Want to throw me into a bin?
Think twice before you do.

Oh, wow, now you're a bird
Both of us can count to three
I am not really a word,
Yet, can you find me?

---

Hint:

> The bird in the third stanza is a seabird.

Comment: Have a +1 for 6k!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you

> The suffix **-ary**?

Turned a second into unessential

> Second**ary**

Do you want to say something?
Hang on, let me write it for you.

> Secret**ary** (thanks @Matt)

Remember that in every word you're saying,
I'm playing a part, it's true.

> Vocabul**ary**

Want to imagine like, anythin'?
I'll prove it wrong, fool you!

> Imagin**ary**

Want to throw me into a bin?
Think twice before you do.

> Bin**ary**

Oh, wow, now you're a bird
Both of us can count to three

> Tern**ary**

I am not really a word,
Yet, can you find me?

> It's a suffix, not a word

Answer (score 4):

What about

> The sound "OCK" (or -ALK or -AUK)

Do you want to say something? / Hang on, let me write it for you.

> Chalk

Remember that in every word you're saying, / I'm playing a part, it's true.

> Talk

Want to imagine like, anythin'? / I'll prove it wrong, fool you!

> Mock

Want to throw me into a bin? / Think twice before you do.

> Balk

Oh, wow, now you're a bird / Both of us can count to three

> Auk (a sea bird with 3 letters)

I am not really a word, / Yet, can you find me?

> You are the sound "OCK". The answer is the sound, not the word.

Title:

> Tick Tock (thanks, Beastly Gerbil)

Comment: Nice try, but no. The title is part of the riddle, indeed.

Comment: The title - tick tock?

Answer (score 0):

Is it ->

> **ou**

Do you want to say something?
Hang on, let me write it for you.

> Do y**ou** want to say something?
>  Hang **on**, let me write it for y**ou**.
>  Inverting **on** gives **ou**

Remember that in every word you're saying,
I'm playing a part, it's true.

> Remember that in every word y**ou**'re saying,
>  I'm playing a part, it's true.
>  ou play's a part in writing "you"

Want to imagine like, anythin'?
I'll prove it wrong, fool you!
Want to throw me into a bin?
Think twice before you do.

> Want to imagine like, anythin'?
>  I'll prove it wr**on**g, fool y**ou**!
>  Want to throw me int**o** a bi**n**?
>  Think twice before y**ou** do.
>  Wrong has an inverted "ou" hence is wrong.

Oh, wow, now you're a bird
Both of us can count to three
I am not really a word,
Yet, can you find me?

> [ou](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CA%BB%C5%8C%CA%BB%C5%AB) is a kind of bird.
>  Not sure about three.. May be some language uses it as 3.
>  It's not really a word and we can find it every where in the riddle.

Also,

> The title says, turned a second into unessential hence it should have been **on** instead of **"ou"** if **n** was left unturned.

Comment: No, no steganography tag neither wordplay :)!

Comment: Oh no!!!!!!! :(

Answer (score 0):

Just a try

> Punctuation

Do you want to say something?
Hang on, let me write it for you.

> Punctuation is there to give a hint on how to say something

Remember that in every word you're saying,
I'm playing a part, it's true.

> Space seems to be a punctuation. It's hard to say anything without it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_(punctuation)

ant to imagine like, anythin'?
I'll prove it wrong, fool you!
Want to throw me into a bin?
Think twice before you do.

> It's important to use it properly ("Toilet only for disabled elderly pregnant children." is pretty different from "Toilet only for disabled, elderly, pregnant, children.")

Oh, wow, now you're a bird
Both of us can count to three
I am not really a word,
Yet, can you find me?

> Obi Wan Kenobi

Comment: I don't get **Obi Wan Kenobi** part. Why that?

Comment: This is not the answer. And I don't understand the last part as well!

Comment: Sorry about that, it's a way to say "I don't know" / "Any answer", but after searching it's only a french expression !

Answer (score 0):

It is a

> Book

Do you want to say something?
Hang on, let me write it for you.

> Books record conversations so "let me write it for you".

Remember that in every word you're saying,
I'm playing a part, it's true.

> Every word we say we learn from books or someone learnt from some book and we learnt from them.

Want to imagine like, anythin'?
I'll prove it wrong, fool you!

> For everything you can imagine, you can find a counter in some or the other book. It might not be true always.

Want to throw me into a bin?
Think twice before you do.

> Books give us knowledge which makes them highly valuable.

Oh, wow, now you're a bird
Both of us can count to three

> This is like a mock, on the idea of that a book is useless to a bird, so both are useless to each other, hence the mock "both of us can count to three"

I am not really a word,
Yet, can you find me?

> It's a book, not only a word.
> P.S. : Another answer based on the same reasoning is "knowledge"

Comment: It's not the answer intended.